# Is there something like Redis DB, but not limited with RAM size?

Tags: database, redis, nosql, bigdata

I'm looking for a database matching these criteria:

- May be non-persistent;
- Almost all keys of DB need to be updated once in 3-6 hours (100M+ keys with total size of 100Gb)
- Ability to quickly select data by key (or Primary Key)
- This needs to be a DBMS (so LevelDB doesn't fit)
- When data is written, DB cluster must be able to serve queries (single nodes can be blocked though)
- Not in-memory – our dataset will exceed the RAM limits
- Horizontal scaling and replication
- Support full rewrite of all data (MongoDB doesn't clear space after deleting data)
- C# and Java support

Here's my process of working with such database:
We've got an analytics cluster that produces 100M records (50GB) of data every 4-6 hours. The data is a "key - array[20]". This data needs to be distributed to users through a front-end system with a rate of 1-10k requests per second. In average, only ~15% of the data is requested, the rest of it will be rewritten in 4-6 hours when the next data set is generated.

What i tried:

1. MongoDB. Datastorage overhead, high defragmentation costs.
2. Redis. Looks perfect, but it's limited with RAM and our data exceeds it.

So the question is: is there anything like Redis, but not limited with RAM size?

Comment: Don't forget to valide an answer!

Comment: You can overcome the RAM scalability barrier by implementing application-side sharding, using the upcoming Redis Cluster (v3.0) or letting the experts handle it (i.e. Redis Labs ;))

Answer (score 28):

**Yes, there are two alternatives to Redis that are not limited by RAM size while remaining compatible with Redis protocol:**

Ardb (C++), replication(Master-Slave/Master-Master): https://github.com/yinqiwen/ardb

> A redis-protocol compatible persistent storage server, support
>   LevelDB/KyotoCabinet/LMDB as storage engine.

Edis (Erlang): https://github.com/cbd/edis

> Edis is a protocol-compatible Server replacement for Redis, written in
>   Erlang. Edis's goal is to be a drop-in replacement for Redis when
>   persistence is more important than holding the dataset in-memory. Edis
>   (currently) uses Google's leveldb as a backend.

**And for completeness here is another data-structures database:**

Hyperdex (Strings, Integers, Floats, Lists, Sets, Maps): http://hyperdex.org/doc/latest/DataTypes/#chap:data-types

> HyperDex is:
>
> - Fast: HyperDex has lower latency, higher throughput, and lower
>     variance than other key-value stores.
> - Scalable: HyperDex scales as
>     more machines are added to the system.
> - Consistent: HyperDex guarantees
>     linearizability for key-based operations. Thus, a read always returns
>     the latest value inserted into the system. Not just “eventually,” but
>     immediately and always.
> - Fault Tolerant: HyperDex automatically
>     replicates data on multiple machines so that concurrent failures, up
>     to an application-determined limit, will not cause data loss.
>     Searchable:
> - HyperDex enables efficient lookups of secondary data
>     attributes.
> - Easy-to-Use: HyperDex provides APIs for a variety of
>     scripting and native languages.
> - Self-Maintaining: A HyperDex is
>     self-maintaining and requires little user maintenance.

Comment: Hello.  Did anybody compared Aerospike to Hyperdex in terms of speed or features?

Comment: Ardb has added support for Facebook's Rocksdb, which is used as the default storage engine

Comment: ardb is nice. we use it on production. It works well.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, SSDB(https://github.com/ideawu/ssdb), it has very similar APIs to Redis: http://www.ideawu.com/ssdb/docs/php/

SSDB supports hash, zset. It use leveldb as storage engine, most data is stored on disk, RAM is used for cache. On our SSDB instance with 300GB data, it only uses 800MB RAM.

Comment: why would ssdb be any better than say postgresql, both store on the disk and while i agree one of them is a key value persistent store and the other one stores structured relational data, this does not cover the fact that connection pooling. data transfer, acknowledgements etc etc are still involved as long as it not maintained in memory

Comment: I've noticed problems with SSDB getting slow and crashing after a few months of usage. It's great at first but becomes unusable after a while in production.

Answer (score 4):

These days you can easily find servers with more than 100 GB of RAM to host a single instance, or you can shard your data and use several servers with less RAM. Storing 100 GB with Redis (in RAM) is not really a problem.

Now if you really want to try a bleeding-edge clone of Redis not limited by RAM size, there is NDS (by Matt Palmer):

- http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2013/04/redis-rethought-exciting-extremes-with-larger-than-memory-datasets/
- https://github.com/mpalmer/redis/tree/nds-2.6

Note that the storage backend of NDS has moved from Kyoto Cabinet to LMDB (a very good package, which also powers OpenLDAP), precisely because of space reclaim issues following deleted keys.

Other solutions - not compatible with Redis - may also suit your needs: Couchbase, and Aerospike, for instance could easily support your throughput. Cassandra and Riak would probably work as well provided you have enough nodes.

Comment: Yes, there are some servers with 100GB of RAM, but not common seen. The data will somehow exceed 100GB, commonly most data is cool and should not resides in RAM, RAM is money cost expensive. According to our experience, Redis should not store more thant 1/3 of total amount of RAM.

Comment: Just as an aside, NDS isn't a Redis clone, it's a fork of Redis integrating disk storage into the main Redis codebase.

Comment: Hello.  Did anybody compared Aerospike to Hyperdex in terms of speed or features?

Comment: With 100GB RAM on one server your Redis dataset is limited to 50GB, or else if your data goes over 50MB then the next time Redis forks to save a snapshot it will run out of memory and switch to read-only mode. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/BestPractices.BGSAVE.html

Comment: Also 100GB of ram is still 100x more expensive than 100GB of disk in 2021